# How to add an Google Chrome application to the taskbar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to add to my application the ability to add it to the taskbar. Is there a API such an opportunity? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Define "application" in this context. A Chrome App as defined [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)?

Comment: sorry:( I do not understand

Comment: So you have a Chrome App (as Xan linked), and you want it to be in the Windows taskbar?  Which version of Windows?  Or are you talking about adding it to the address bar, next to where you type the url (this would be a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction))?  What does your application do?  Why do you want to add it to the taskbar?

Comment: I want to add it to the Windows taskbar. Create button in the app to add it to the taskbar. Or add it to the taskbar immediately after installation. Is that possible? In API Google Chrome is such a method? It would be very convenient for quick access to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no API for this. When it's launched, it will appear on the taskbar, and then the user can right-click on the icon and pin it.

Comment: That, or right-click in the app launcher and select Create Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

(I assume by "taskbar" you mean shortcuts/favorites icons on the taskbar)

Different OS's have different ways to do this.

On Linux, chrome apps are put in the start menu under a "Chrome Apps" group.  From there, right-click to create shortcuts, add to panel, or favorites.

There doesn't appear to be an api to do this automatically: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index

You're best bet may be to show the user how to access the app:

- "Apps" on bookmark bar in Chrome
- "Chrome Apps" in start menu